# Find number of integers in a range

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a formula to count the number of cells in a Range that are integers. I am using

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(A2))=TRUE,1,0)
```

to find if the cell contains a number or not. I believe this can be achieved using INDIRECT() and SUM(). Could someone be kind enough to lead me in the right direction?

Comment: To clarify; do you need to count just the integers? i.e. not count any number with fractional part?

Comment: I want to count the number of cells with integers. ie if in a range A1:C3 4 cells contain integer data I want my output as 4.

Comment: Thanks to whoever suggested the COUNTIF() function. Sad that you had to delete the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure COUNTIF() was general enough; the criteria argument is quite restrictive. The fact that you want to discount strings, blanks and numbers with decimals is probably too much for it. Still, if anyone can do this with a COUNTIF() I'll upvote and you ought to accept that solution as it would be clearer than my array solution.

Comment: I actually did it using COUNTIF(), this is what I came up with `=COUNTIF(A2:AA2,">0")+COUNTIF(A2:A2,"<0")+COUNTIF(A2:AA2,"=0")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
 =SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A4),IF(ROUND(A1:A4,0)-A1:A4=0,1,0)))
```

Where A1:A4 is the range.

It's an array formula, meaning you need to type Ctrl+Shift+Return when entering it into a cell.

Only integers will be included; other values (strings and numbers with decimal part) will be discounted. It works by comparing a number to its rounded value.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

```
=COUNT(1/(INT(A1:A10)=A1:A10))
```

array entered with ctrl+shift+enter